# When does Magento consider a cart to be abandoned? Where's that time limit set?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, shopping-cart

If left to default settings, what circumstances would have to occur for Magento 1.7 to consider a cart abandoned? Where is the code that makes this determination located?

I know that this is probably set somewhere in the quote, but I can't find it for the life of me.

I've done some Googling, but like so many Magento questions I'm left empty handed. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you probably know the setting is located here:

**Admin => system => Configuration => Sales => Checkout => Shopping Cart => Quote Lifetime (days)**

This will add the setting to the database (core_config_data table) with path:

**checkout/cart/delete_quote_after**

This path is used in the code on:

**app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Observer.php line 54**

So when someone is adding something to a cart it will be updated. When a customer logs in and his cart is there it will be updated. When a cart is not updated for the last 30 days. It will be removed.

**Extra information:**

In case you wonder when this code is used, It is used by the cronjob of magento.

check:
**App/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml** line 1732

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <sales_clean_quotes>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>sales/observer::cleanExpiredQuotes</model>
            </run>
        </sales_clean_quotes>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As an oft quoted sick joke, the observer only cleans out completed orders -> `$quotes->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 0);` and as abandoned carts never get `is_active` set from 1 to 0, abandoned guest carts have infinite staying power and after a year, can consume considerable database storage space.

Comment: I read that that the "Quote Lifetime (days)" only applies to (anonymous) nog-logged-in customers. But a cart from a logged-in user *never* expires. Have you come across this difference in behavior?

Comment: @khoekman **"Check code here"** Links must be updated, they do not exist anymore.

Comment: @divy3993 thanks for pointing out. i have removed the links to the old source code.

Answer (score 0):

The question was about when a cart becomes abandoned, not when the quote expires.  As Magento doesn't have abandoned cart functionality, it's arbitrary.  The various extensions to add it let you set it.

Comment: Magento does have an abandoned cart "functionality" in the sense that it has carts it considers abandoned, it just doesn't have a mechanism for doing anything with said carts.

Answer (score 0):

In our e-commerce we've overridden the method `cleanExpiredQuotes` inside *app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Observer.php*

Our business rule looks like this:

```
$quotes = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection();     
$quotes->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('to' => date("Y-m-d", time() - $lifetime)));

$quotes->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
foreach ($this->getExpireQuotesAdditionalFilterFields() as $field => $condition) {
    $quotes->addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
}
$quotes->walk('delete');
```