# Magento Clear Guest or Registered Users Cart in 10 minutes

Tags: magento, session, cart

Hi i want to clear the customers cart in 10 minutes (guest or registered users).
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schedule a cron job

How to schedule a cron job you can get it from
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Now this would run after every some seconds

Check the customer quote created time

Actually magento creates the cart details is quote item. If you want more details on this check sales/quote model

If the time exceeds 30 min delete the quote. For that you have to run sql queries

If you still need some details let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Run a script which would run every 20 - 30 sec to set the timer

If the timer exceeds 10 mins (customer is idle) clear all session

Comment: hello see link may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148275/when-does-magento-consider-a-cart-to-be-abandoned-wheres-that-time-limit-set

Comment: MagikVishal has a good solution to what you want. Try to implement this. I am posting the details of it by copying it in answer below

Comment: Hi sandeep im a newbie, (and not a Magento certified Engineer like u), Can u give me more explanation that i can able to understand. Do u mean running a cron job? And link suggested by MagikVishal i tried Admin => system => Configuration => Sales => Checkout => Quote Lifetime (days) to set to 0.0006 in decimals (think it expire in seconds) also not working for me....