# Get all abandoned carts in Magento

Tags: php, magento, cart, quote

How could I get all the abandoned carts with customer's email (programatically)?

What does Magento consider as being abandoned? Not updated in the last day?

Answer (score 2):

Standalone file that can be used anywhere you wish.

Either filter by is_active or check if any of your orders contain the quote id ( in which case the quote became an order so obviously not abandoned ).

```
require_once( 'app/Mage.php' );

umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

$sCustomerId = 1;
$oQuotes = Mage::getModel( 'sales/quote' )->getCollection();
$oQuotes->addFieldToFilter( 'customer_id', $sCustomerId );
foreach( $oQuotes as $oQuote )
{
    var_dump( $oQuote->getData( 'is_active' ) );
    $oOrders = Mage::getModel( 'sales/order' )->getCollection();
    $oOrders->addFieldToFilter( 'quote_id', $oQuote->getId() );
    var_dump( 'Became an order?: ' );
    var_dump( $oOrders->count() );

    $oItems = Mage::getModel( 'sales/quote_item' )
        ->getCollection()
        ->setQuote( $oQuote );
    foreach( $oItems as $oItem )
    {
        var_dump( $oItem->getProduct()->getId() );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The admin section in Magento has this functionality built in. In the admin section visit `Reports->Shopping Cart->Abandoned carts`.

This page contains an admin grid with all the abandoned carts and the customer email attached. It even gives you the standard export functionality so you can get a file in different formats containing all the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

This link will give your all answers [abondoned cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148275/when-does-magento-consider-a-cart-to-be-abandoned-wheres-that-time-limit-set). Hope this will helpful to you.